# how to merge list of lists without changing the order of sublists in python?

Tags: python, list, merge

merge list of lists for example

```
list_of_lists = [['NA','NA','NA','0,678'], ['0.327','NA','NA','NA'], ...]
```

I want

```
merged = ['0.327','NA','NA','0,678']
```

Please comment.

Comment: And what if *both* lists have a value != `'NA'`?

Comment: I don't see any such condition in my data

Comment: Not in the example data here, no. But the possibility will never arise in your actual use-case?

Comment: I am sure it won't arise in my data

Comment: But there can be more than one list and they all can be in a list of lists format such as [['NA','NA','NA','0,678'],['0.327','NA','NA','NA'],...so on]

Comment: Your question is then *unclear*. You only have 2 lists in your question, each a simple list. I've updated the example to what I now understand your real question to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with a nested generator expression to pick the first non-`NA` element, together with `zip()`:

```
merged = [next((el for el in elements if el != 'NA'), 'NA') for elements in zip(*list_of_lists)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [['NA','NA','NA','0,678'], ['0.327','NA','NA','NA']]
>>> [next((el for el in elements if el != 'NA'), 'NA') for elements in zip(*list_of_lists)]
['0.327', 'NA', 'NA', '0,678']
```

The `next((...), default)` call expression will pick the *first* element that is not equal to `'NA'`, falling back to `'NA'` if no such element exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there both list do not have values in the same position (as suggested by Martijn Pieters) then you could use:

```
for i in range(len(l1)): 
    l1[i] = l2[i] if l1[i] == 'NA' and l2[i] != 'NA' else l1[i]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list_of_lists = [['NA','NA','NA','0,678'], ['0.327','NA','NA','NA']]
>>> from itertools import ifilter # Py3k doesn't need import, use filter built-in
>>> [next(ifilter('NA'.__ne__, col), 'NA') for col in zip(*list_of_lists)]
['0.327', 'NA', 'NA', '0,678']
```